# Ember-cli-sass not creating .css file

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I've just installed and created `app/styles/app.scss`, but when I start with ember server the `.css` file is not created. Is there any other set up I need, other than `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-sass`?

I've also added this to my Brocfile.js, and run `ember build`:

Edit: I've also tried compiling manually by adding this to my Brocfile.js and running `ember build`:

```
var compileSass = require('broccoli-sass');

var app = new EmberApp();

var sassImportPaths = [
  'app/styles'
];

var appCss = compileSass(sassImportPaths, './app/styles/app.scss', './assets/app.css');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install with `ember install ember-cli-sass` and after rename app.css to app.scss in `app/styles/`and restart the server. Should work.

Answer (score 2):

See if below will help you

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  sassOptions: {
     includePaths: [
        'app/styles'
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

I just ran `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-sass` again and it was all good. Everything should work out of the box if you install it and change `app/styles/app.css` to `app/styles/app.scss`.